# Как получить объект из исполненного промиса?

Tags: javascript

Не могу получить нужный мне объект из промиса (вместо этого мне выдаётся сам промис).

Функция получающая данные:

```
async function getapi(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => { 
        return response.json().then((data) => {
            return data.main.temp;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }) })};
```

Получение объекта:

```
temp = getapi(api_url)    
console.log(temp);
```

По идее должны выводиться данные, но вместо этого выводится это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы можете заметить всё работает (потому что нужные данные есть и они окрашены синим), но нужно чтобы выводились именно данные, а не промис. Как же это сделать?

Comment: У вас `getapi` возвращает промис, поэтому надо работать с промисом, а не данными. Т.е. использовать `then` или асинхронную функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getapi(api_url).then(console.log);
```

или

```
(async function main() {
    let temp = await getapi(api_url); 
    console.log(temp);
})()
```